# Changed files check via Git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-status

I have a Wordpress file tree (wp-admin,wp-content etc) from April 2016 with the .git folder locally on my PC. I have just downloaded the latest version of that file tree from my server and wish to see the difference between these folders. Is there a quick way to see which files have "changed" or comparing without having to copy the new folder over and overwrite the old files?

Any other folder comparison tools would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply copy the `.git` folder into the new tree. Or just use changed git-dir for a git commands like status/diff/etc, e.g.:

```
cd new/wp/file/tree
export GIT_DIR=/old/wp/file/tree/.git
git status
```

But I don't see the reason why do not you want to overwrite old files. You could do override (just don't touch the `.git` folder), see difference, do some commits and undo overwrites you don't want by `checkout` or `reset` commands.